# How do I find a spanning set of the kernel of this transformation: T(A) = A + A^T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So I know the kernel of T(A) = A + A^T (where A is any n x n matrix) can be described as an anti-symmetric matrix (also called a skew-symmetric matrix).

What I don't know is how to find and write the spanning set for this kernel.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Any matrix $A$ in the kernel satisfies $A+A^T=0$, or $A=-A^T$. This means for the matrix, $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$.

With this relation, if $i=j$, $a_{ij}=0$. If $i>j$, then $a_{ij}$ is determined by $a_{ji}$. If $i<j$ there are no restriction for $a_{ij}$.

These are the only restriction, giving a kernel of dimension $\frac {n(n-1)}2$, given by the basis $e_{ij}-e_{ji}$ for all $i<j$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot more sense! Would there be a specific way to express this by saying "the spanning set of the kernel is: span{?}"

Comment: @SatanLucifer Yes, it's the span of the basis I gave.

Comment: It took a day for it to click, but now it makes perfect sense! Thank you so very much, again! Your help is invaluable to me :))))!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal M$ the set of $n \times n$ matrices.

It is well known that we have the direct sum:

$$\underbrace{\mathcal M}_{\text{dimension} \ n^2}=\underbrace{\mathcal S}_{\text{dimension} \ \tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}} \oplus \underbrace{\mathcal A}_{\text{dimension} \tfrac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

where $\mathcal S$, resp. $\mathcal A$ = set of symmetric, resp. antisymmetric matrices: (recall: antisymmetric means $A^T=-A$ ; $\mathcal A$ is clearly your kernel).

A basis of $\mathcal A$ is given by matrices

$$E_{i,j}=e_i e_j^T-e_je_i^T \ \ (1 \le i<j\le n)$$

where $e_i$ is the $i$-th unit vector.

For example, in dimension $n=2$, the only one is:

$$E_{1,2}=\binom{1}{0}(0 \ 1)-\binom{0}{1}(1 \ 0)=\begin{pmatrix} \ \ 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

For example in dimension $3$, an antisymmetric matrix has this (unique) decomposition on the basis $E_{12}, E_{13},E_{23}$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

The fact that in general the $E_{i,j}$ constitute a basis of $\mathcal A$ can be explained by the fact that there are $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ such matrices and they are independent.